Convert a key-value list into a keyname: key, valuename:value dictionary using JMESPath
I have a list that looks like:
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4"
}

I need to convert into a format like below.
[
  {
    "headername" : "key1",
    "headervalue" : "value1"
  },
  {
    "headername" : "key2",
    "headervalue" : "value2"
  },
  {
    "headername" : "key3",
    "headervalue" : "value3"
  },
  {
    "headername" : "key4",
    "headervalue" : "value4"
  }
]

I need to use JMESPath since the product I work supports it. And if anyone is curious, the above format makes it easy to pass to a table variable.
I tried a couple of JMESPath expression, but they don't generate the expected output.
First Try:
map(&{ headervalue : @, headerkey : @ } values(@))
Seconds Try:
{headerkey: keys(@), headervalue : values(@)}

It's possible but with an hardcoded solution, so if you have 100 keys you will probably write a solution with 100 line of code. Do you know how many key you can have ? If the object is simple like you example and the structure will not change with time so an hardcoded solution is okay. Tell me If you still want it.
